# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency warning when creating production build for IPFS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, ipfs

I am trying to create a production build for IPFS using Next.js, when I try to run `yarn build` I run into this error:

```
68:8  Warning: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'updateUI'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

./components/ManualHeader.jsx
16:8  Warning: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'enableWeb3'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
27:8  Warning: React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'Moralis' and 'deactivateWeb3'. Either include them or remove the dependency array.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

info  - Need to disable some ESLint rules? Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#disabling-rules
info  - Linting and checking validity of types
info  - Creating an optimized production build ...
```

The `info -Creating an optimized production build ...` just keeps flashing.

I tried to go into the `LotteryEntrance.js` and the `Manualheader.jsx` to remove the missing dependency and was only able to get rid of the `UpdatedUI` error and `enableWeb3` error and wasn't able to get correct the `Moralis` and `deactiveWeb3` error.

I apologize if this post is horribly formatted or asked, I am new to this and not very good at understanding how to ask what is going wrong.

Comment: Can you share both `LotteryEntrance` and `Manualheader` components' code? You need to add the variables the warning is complaining about to the `useEffect`s dependencies array where they're used.

Answer (score 0):

The build was getting hung because the server was still running in the back ground
killing the server terminal and running it again allowed me to build it